# How to copy data from one database to another in Google Cloud

Tags: database, postgresql, google-cloud-platform

**I am working on Google Cloud App Engine Platform.**
I have to copy the data from one database of one instance to another database of another instance:

***My databases are both Postgres 13***

```
Instance a:  
    database a_a;

Instance b:
    database b_b;
```

I have to copy "a_a"'s data into b_b;

I just want to copy the data without copying the entire database structure.

Is there a way to export and then import the data?

How can I do it?

Comment: Edit your question with details. 1) What data do you need to copy (row, table, database)? 2) Typically you must export and import data. Look into the **pg_dump** and **psql** programs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved By Using `gcloud sql export sql gs://<bucket_name>/sqldumpfile.gz --database=db_name --offload` and the right permission for the service account.

All the source is [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/import-export/import-export-sql#gcloud)

Comment: This answer is incomplete. Your question does not clearly state the problem and provide the necessary details to be useful to others. Your answer does not provide context on how to export and import data nor the required permissions and options. This answer should be posted as comments in your question.